# Can't display very high images using the flutter image widget

Tags: flutter, image

I have a comic reading app built using Flutter, this app requires to display sometimes a very high quality images with a high ratio. when displaying these images, the flutter image widget and every other widget i used minimize the quality of the picture. I tried using a lot of packages but all of them are based on the image widget. The only thing that worked was using a WebView. which isn't a very good solution for my case. I google this for more than a month, all solutions sugges trying FilterQuality.Medium, which is good if the image was not a very big image. Images below shows:

1- Displaying the image in a browser:

[image]

2- Displaying the image in image using FilterQuality.medium:

[image]

3- Displaying the image in image using FilterQuality.none:

[image]

EDIT:

for example the shown image dimension is 720x14266.

I'm trying to loaded from the internet and show it into a scroll view filling the device width without loosing the image quality.

Here's an example url of the image showed above:
https://onma.top/uploads/manga/they_say_i_was_born_kingsdaughter/chapters/166/01.jpg

Comment: Can you post url of one image please? Just to test it.

Comment: @KaushikChandru I forgot that, here's a link: https://onma.top/uploads/manga/they_say_i_was_born_kingsdaughter/chapters/166/01.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Brother, how are these images being called? Are you using NetworkImage or AssetImage?

If you are using NetworkImage, then there is nothing I can do because the image is divided into packages and then on display they are combined, which will lose some quality. If you are using AssetImage, then there will be no loss, but the max resolution will be set according to the device output capability.

If a device is 1080p, then the output  image will be 1080p.

Comment: I'm using network image, tried it with caching and without caching.  I need a way to load an image from the internet without quality loss.

Comment: Thank you for your first answer.

I have some feedback regarding your answer:
- Please don't don't use phrases like "Brother", they do not contribute to your answer.
- Please provide references for your statements like the downsampling of images if the device can only handle a lower resolution.
- I challenge your explanation about images being transferred packet by packet which results in quality loss. How would that happen? The bytes are transferred "as-is" from the source to the destination. Putting the bytes together at the destination will not result in a quality loss by itself. But that's

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ResizeImage` widget. You can set it in the initstate and use that in build method like the following

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ResizeImage? img;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    img = ResizeImage(
        NetworkImage(
            'https://onma.top/uploads/manga/they_say_i_was_born_kingsdaughter/chapters/166/01.jpg'),
        width: 500,
        allowUpscaling: true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Image(image: img!)));
  }
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: It still the same result since it's still using the image widget, maybe open the image in the browser, and compare with it, the difference will be clear.

Comment: it shows good result in my device, but maybe try taking a release build and check once